# How to resolve blocking issues with netty?

Tags: java, netty, amazon-sqs

we have some challenges on using the Netty library. The library should be non-blocking, so all requests should be sent to a separate task. We solve this by sending the messages from our clients to the Amazon Simple Queue Service (SQS). The queue will be read from an other service and that particular service will write the message to some other queue.

Here comes the tricky part. Now we have to read this queue. What are the best options to handle this problem?

At the moment we schedule a task within the handler.channelActive method

```
sf = ctx.executor().scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> {
                        System.out.println("Calling..." + ctx.channel().id().asShortText());                       

                        handleWriteAction();

                    }, WRITE_TIMER_IN_SECONDS, WRITE_TIMER_IN_SECONDS, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

The problem with this is it look like it blocks the incoming messages. Some clients do have a delay of a few seconds. That's no problem, but others do have a delay of a minute.

So, how could we solve the read of the queue without blocking the incoming messages?

The are using Netty 4.1.13 and the clients do have an open connection with our netty server.

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for non-blocking or asynchronous I/O, not a queue.

Comment: Following up on EJP's comment, I thought I read that the most recent Amazon API release was non-blocking. Have you looked at that ?

Comment: Read from another thread, by default only 1 thread manages a single channel to prevent annoying thread safety bugs code